# override pattern ignored when setting properties logging.pattern.console or logging.pattern.level

Tags: spring-boot

Using spring-boot 1.3.2

I am trying to override logback pattern in application.properties file but no matter what pattern I put in there the default pattern from spring-boot jar xml is always invoked. I can successfully adjust the *logging.level* value from *INFO -> DEBUG* and can observe the changes in the output but the logging.pattern.[console | level] is always ignored.

```
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
logging.pattern.console=user:%X{username} %X{ipAddress} %5p
#logging.pattern.console=%5p    #Also ignored 
#logging.pattern.level=%5p      #Also ignored
```

Yes, I am trying to use MDC values but even if I do not use the MDC values the 
override is still ignored.

Any ideas on how to further trouble shoot?

Here is my classpath hierarchy with any dependency that has the string **"log"** in in the name.

[image: Here is my classpath hierarchy with any dependency that has the string "log" in in the name.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen when there's an unwanted `logback.xml` configuration file on the classpath that overrides Spring Boot's configuration. You can force Logback to output information about its configuration via the `logback.statusListenerClass` system property. For example, you could add the following to the JVM arguments when you launch your application:

```
-Dlogback.statusListenerClass=ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener
```

If Spring Boot's defaults are being used, and therefore `logging.console.pattern` should work, you'll see output similar to the following:

```
12:38:27,471 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
12:38:27,489 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
12:38:27,489 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.xml]
12:38:27,492 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Setting up default configuration.
```

If a stray `logback.xml` is being found somewhere on the classpath, you'll see output similar to the following:

```
12:41:06,179 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
12:41:06,198 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
12:41:06,198 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at […]
```

Comment: that is exactly what is happening? Looks like spring-data-neo4j has the rogue logback.xml embedded in the jar. IS there a way to force using spring-boot default logback.xml default?

Comment: I tried setting `logging.config = classpath:org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml` but it chokes on startup java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:

Comment: The file's designed to be included in your own `logback.xml` rather than being referenced directly.

Comment: I'd recommend opening a bug against Neo4J. IMO, their neo4j-server jar really shouldn't have a `logback.xml` in it.

Comment: it's actually inside `spring-data-neo4j-4.0.0.RELEASE-tests.jar`

Comment: That's an unusual dependency. Do you need it? There's also one in `neo4j-server`: `Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/Users/awilkinson/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/app/neo4j-server/2.2.5/neo4j-server-2.2.5.jar!/logback.xml]`

Comment: I see what was happening... I was bringing in those depedencies as test jars for integration tests (embedded InProcess neo4j server) as `<type>test-jar</type>` but I didn't explicitly include `<scope>test</scope>` so they had default compile time scope. After adding test scope now the default spring-boot logback config is being picked up. But this could still break my unit/integration test logging? Should I still file the bug?

Comment: IMO, it's worth filing one against neo4j-server. I'm not sure sure about spring-data-neo4j-4.0.0.RELEASE-tests.