# logback-spring.xml not working with goal repackage?

Tags: spring-boot, logback

My intention in the first place is to disable the console output in specific active profiles.

I've setup a new tomcat (8.5.12) and deployed only a "spring-boot-hello-world" app, Similar to this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/).

The packaging type is a classic `war` - therefore I've changed my pom as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>

  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <finalName>foo</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

and extended my Application from `SpringBootServletInitializer`. Instead of using `System.out.println` I've added an `org.slf4j.Logger`.

If I now add the `logback-spring.xml` from this [howto](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging-fileonly) I get the following error:

```
16:52:01.365 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.exception-conversion-word]
16:52:01.367 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.exception-conversion-word] not found - trying original name [logging.exception-conversion-word]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.exception-conversion-word] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.exception-conversion-word].
```

Based on this [SO-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148254/override-pattern-ignored-when-setting-properties-logging-pattern-console-or-logg) I've added `-Dlogback.statusListenerClass=ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener` when starting my tomcat. This leads to the following result.

```
16:22:33,891 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
16:22:33,891 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
16:22:33,891 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/tmp/apache-tomcat-8.5.12/webapps/foo/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
```

Looking at the specified location, there are the following files/folders:

```
ls /tmp/apache-tomcat-8.5.12/webapps/foo/WEB-INF/classes/
hello  logback-spring.xml
```

If I add e.g. a (valid) `logback-dev.xml`, I get the following result in `catalina.out`:

```
17:44:46,698 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
17:44:46,702 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
17:44:46,703 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.xml]
```

Is it normal that logback things that the `logback-spring.xml` is a `logback.xml`? Or might this be a bug?

---

Working with an 'ordinary' `logback.xml` does not allow me to use e.g. `<springProfile name="dev">` see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logback-extensions).

If I want to work with different profiles the only solution I found is to provide a `logback-{stage}.xml` and add a `logging.config=classpath:logback-{stage}.xml` in the related `application-{stage}.properties` file - <strike>this seems to work.</strike> Does not work either! I can add the `logback-{stage}.xml` without effect. But as soon as I include it to `logging.config=classpath:logback-{stage}.xml` I get:

```
09:26:35.084 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [LOGGING_patternlevel]
09:26:35.084 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [LOGGING_patternlevel] threw NamingException with message: Name [LOGGING_patternlevel] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [LOGGING_patternlevel].. Returning null
```