# logging.pattern.console is ignored in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, logback, slf4j

I have a Spring-Boot application (version 2.5.4) with application.properties file to configure log behaviour.

I try to change the console pattern for logging, but it is ignored.

```
logging.pattern.console=test %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n
```

Strange is, that it works **locally** on my machine (I can see rows starting with test), **but not on the server-side**. On the server side, default pattern is used.

All other parameters as follow **work locally and server-side**.

```
logging.file.name=/tmp/mylog.log
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size=100MB
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-history=10
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.file-name-pattern=/tmp/mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
```

With current setup I don't have a logback.xml in my project. So there is no overwriting.

When adding the `logback.xml` and configure the same using the XML syntax its also working **locally** and **server-side**.

I would like to use the application-.properties file, because of easier syntax and easier profile handling.

Because I don't know how to debug this, I am asking here. Can anyone guess what could be the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148254/override-pattern-ignored-when-setting-properties-logging-pattern-console-or-logg

Comment: Server side!? there must be some higher priority property! Please check for a env variable (LOGGING_PATTERN_CONSOLE)

Comment: with ascending priority: **5. OS environment variables. 6. Java System properties (System.getProperties()). 7. JNDI attributes from java:comp/env. 8. ServletContext init parameters. 9. ServletConfig init parameters. 10. Properties from SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property). 11. Command line arguments.** 12-13 test related. **14. Devtools global settings properties in the $HOME/.config/spring-boot** directory when devtools is active.[link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)